# Anything like Scroll Lock key in the bash of Linux subsystem in windows 10

Tags: ls, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I use `ls` or `ll` for some directory, the output is so long and annoyingly the cmd windows can only go back for several lines...

If I use `ll | less`, all the color info is missing.

Is there anything that works like the Scroll Lock key which can display the output page by page?

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but try `ll --color=always|less`

Answer (score 0):

Either use <kbd>Ctrl S</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl Q</kbd> to stop/resume output, or:

Read `man less`:

```
   -r or --raw-control-chars
          Causes "raw" control characters to be displayed.  The default is
          to display control characters  using  the  caret  notation;  for
          example, a control-A (octal 001) is displayed as "^A".  Warning:
          when the -r option is used, less cannot keep track of the actual
          appearance  of  the screen (since this depends on how the screen
          responds to each type  of  control  character).   Thus,  various
          display  problems  may result, such as long lines being split in
          the wrong place.

   -R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
          Like -r, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences  are  output  in
          "raw"  form.   Unlike  -r,  the  screen appearance is maintained
          correctly in most cases.   ANSI  "color"  escape  sequences  are
          sequences of the form:

               ESC [ ... m

          where  the  "..." is zero or more color specification characters
          For the purpose of keeping  track  of  screen  appearance,  ANSI
          color  escape sequences are assumed to not move the cursor.  You
          can make less think that characters other than "m" can end  ANSI
          color  escape  sequences  by  setting  the  environment variable
          LESSANSIENDCHARS to the list of characters which can end a color
          escape  sequence.   And  you can make less think that characters
          other than the standard ones may appear between the ESC and  the
          m  by  setting  the environment variable LESSANSIMIDCHARS to the
          list of characters which can appear.
```

and do `ll --color=always | less -R`